# ORA-01045 when attempting to connect to PDB. User has CREATE SESSION privilege, but I Oracle says they don't

Tags: oracle

The user has been granted `CREATE SESSION` but i can only connect to CDB and not the PDB. Why is this? I'm trying this in SQL developer. I have Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create a common user instead of creating a user in PDB?

For a common user C##test from CDB

```
grant create session to c##test container=all;
```

or

From PDB login as sysdba/dba/pdbadmin

```
grant create session to c##test;
```